# Advantages / reasons to use .NET NT services over SSIS packages, for data integration in SQL Server

Tags: .net, ssis

I have seen, in many organisation, a lot of "batches" written in .NET to import data into SQL Server.

While I understand the need to not duplicate business logic, I always thought that SSIS package would be faster and cheaper to realise. Especially since you can include .NET code (using DLL or Web services / Rest Service) in your SSIS packages.

What advantages would exist to choose a custom .NET batch over SSIS, to integrate data ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of reasons that I could think of:

1. Compatibility with SQL Server Express, since SSIS is not available.
2. Avoidance of SSIS's occasionally infuriating UI experience.
3. Avoidance of breaking updates in SSIS.  We recently had to upgrade our packages from 2008 to 2014 and it was not always a smooth process.

I'm sure there are others as well as counterpoints to the above, as this question is close to being opinion-based.

Comment: I do not think that it's that close to being opinion-based but I agree that at the end, opinion is what will prevail.